# Call Custom aAction from Liferay Theme

Tags: liferay

I have A Custom Theme project & A Custom portlet project in liferay.
I want to call a custom action which is in Custom portlet from `navigation.vm` File of Theme Project.

actionurl is : `/c/journal/upload_article` which is called from same portlet project successfully.

How to call this from theme project?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds weird to "call" an action from a theme. If you embed a form to upload content *on every page*, naturally, you'd need a target for the upload. But still, the theme seems to be the wrong place to do so.

Nevertheless: It seems that you're using a non-custom URL for uploading (`/c/journal/upload_article`). You can do so from wherever in HTML. The big question then is: Where will you end up after the upload, as it doesn't happen from within a page.

If you need a proper portlet URL on an individual page, and want to return to the same page, the best way forward is to embed a portlet in the theme (which makes a great search term for Liferay's documentation). From that portlet you can utilize Liferay's API to do what you're trying to achieve. Make it a very lightweight portlet, because, well, it will be embedded on every single page.